# Atributo download, nova linha em arquivo de texto

Tags: javascript, html, download

Estou tentando fazer download de um arquivo de texto com informações vindas de um `array` mas gostaria de separar estes valores em nova linha... tentei algumas abordagens más sem sucesso o resultado permanece em apenas uma linha.

```js
let codes = [
    'sajkhasjdgsa456456',
    'hjkgd576k3nt67sdffd',
    'kjhkdgyfg8677dsfbjk',
    'mcvsaud423409878gsad',
    '123786dhjfsd734234ds45'
]

$('#download-link').on('click', function(code) {
   let data = ''
   for (let i = 0; i < codes.length; i++) {
        data += codes[i] + '\n'
   }
   $(this).attr('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + data)
})

$('#download-link2').on('click', function(code) {
   let data = codes.join('\n')
   $(this).attr('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + data)
})
```

```html
<a id="download-link" href="" download="codes.txt">baixar</a>
<br>
<a id="download-link2" href="" download="codes-2.txt">baixar 2</a>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mude o `\n` por `%0D%0A` que já vai funcionar.
Fonte: [resposta no StackOverflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4768124/6036208).

Answer (score 6):

Basta usar [**`escape`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape) (já que não tem acentos ou coisa assim), deve ficar assim:

> Se tiver que trabalhar com acentos ou tiver espaços ou o sinal  `+` talvez tenha que usar [**`encodeURI`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) ou [**`encodeURIComponent`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) no lugar de `escape`, no seu exemplo como só tem caracteres "aleatórios" como A-Z e 0-9 o `escape` deve funcionar bem

```js
let codes = [
    'sajkhasjdgsa456456',
    'hjkgd576k3nt67sdffd',
    'kjhkdgyfg8677dsfbjk',
    'mcvsaud423409878gsad',
    '123786dhjfsd734234ds45'
]

$('#download-link').on('click', function(code) {
   let data = ''
   for (let i = 0; i < codes.length; i++) {
        data += codes[i] + '\n'
   }

   data = escape(data);

   $(this).attr('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + data)
})

$('#download-link2').on('click', function(code) {
   let data = codes.join('\n');

   data = escape(data);

   $(this).attr('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + data)
})
```

```html
<a id="download-link" href="" download="codes.txt">baixar</a>
<br>
<a id="download-link2" href="" download="codes-2.txt">baixar 2</a>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### Quebra de linha no "Bloco de notas" (notepad.exe)

A quebra de linha `\n` não funciona em alguns programas com o `notepad.exe` do Windows, isso talvez deva ser por causa de alguma necessidade com **retrocompatibilidade** (backwards compatibility)

Para que o documento seja visível no `notepad.exe` você deverá trocar `\n` por `\r\n`, então para explicar:

- `\n` é o *line feed* (LF)
- `\r` é *carriage return* (CR)

O `LF` era usado como quebra de linha em sistemas baseados em Linux e Unix, `CR` era usado por sistemas Mac (antes do OSX), já o `CRLF` era usado por sistemas Microsoft antigos, no entanto creio que hoje todos sistemas usem apenas `LF`, o motivo do Notepad.exe ainda usar o `CRLF` deve ser para manter a compatibilidade com arquivos antigos e claro que hoje temos softwares que substituem bem o notepad tradicional em Windows (como Notepad++, SublimeText, etc), então se quer manter uma retrocompatibilidade troque no seu código o `.join('\n')` por `.join('\r\n')`

Exemplo:

```js
let codes = [
    'sajkhasjdgsa456456',
    'hjkgd576k3nt67sdffd',
    'kjhkdgyfg8677dsfbjk',
    'mcvsaud423409878gsad',
    '123786dhjfsd734234ds45'
]

$('#download-link').on('click', function(code) {
   let data = ''
   for (let i = 0; i < codes.length; i++) {
        data += codes[i] + '\r\n'
   }

   data = escape(data);

   $(this).attr('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + data)
})

$('#download-link2').on('click', function(code) {
   let data = codes.join('\r\n');

   data = escape(data);

   $(this).attr('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + data)
})
```

```html
<a id="download-link" href="" download="codes.txt">baixar</a>
<br>
<a id="download-link2" href="" download="codes-2.txt">baixar 2</a>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Seu exemplo não surtiu mudança alguma?

Comment: Acabei de testar seu `snippet` e o resultado é o mesmo do meu... tudo em uma só linha. Sim os valores de meu `array` são somente alfa-numéricos. Obrigado por sua resposta más optei pela proposta de @Bruno Romualdo que de fato resultou em novas linhas.

Comment: @LauroMoraes não você esta enganado, você deve estar abrindo no bloco de notas, antigamente softwares windows usavam `\R\N` hoje só usam `\N`, logo o problema não é o código e sim que você esta usando um software bem arcaico que só se mantem usando `\R\N` pra quebras de linhas devido a retrocompatibilidade.

Comment: Sim estou usando Windows8 64bits e Notepad é o programa padrão para abrir `.txt`, agradeço seu esforço e a edição de sua resposta com "mais esclarecimentos" contudo meu voto já foi dado agraciando a resposta que primeiro solucionou a questão. Mais uma vez grato.

Comment: @LauroMoraes votos de aceitação podem mudar, e como expliquei se houver diferentes caracteres você terá problema, mas faça como desejar.